# How to get a value in a file with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, yq

I am trying to read a value in a `yaml` file from a bash script

This is how my yaml looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  consul-write: 100
kind: Secret
```

I need to get the value of `consul-write`. (in this case it is, `100`)

How can I get this value using  `bash`

this command outputs the above yaml

```
kubectl get secrets consul-write -n test -o yaml
```

This is what I tried. Can someone please help me?

```
NAMESPACE=$1
TOKEN_NAME=$2

KUBE_GET=$(kubectl get secrets $TOKEN_NAME -n $NAMESPACE -o yaml)

echo $KUBE_GET
```

Comment: Add how you are calling it and what it prints

Comment: I just cal it. and the output is the same `yaml` output. I need to cut that output and get the `consul-write` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk to pick out field 2 on the line matching TOKEN_NAME

```
 kubectl get secrets $TOKEN_NAME -n $NAMESPACE -o yaml | awk -vns=$TOKEN_NAME '$1 ~ ns {print $2}'
```

EDIT: fixed variable and multi-line output.

Comment: This gives empty output.

Comment: Bash was flattening the string, and I was using the wrong variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NAMESPACE="$1"
TOKEN_NAME="$2"

KUBE_GET=$(kubectl get secrets "$TOKEN_NAME" -n "$NAMESPACE" -o yaml)

grep "$TOKEN_NAME" <<< "$KUBE_GET" | sed 's/.*: \(.*\)$/\1/'
```

**Explanation:**

This will find the first line containing the given token name:

```
grep "$TOKEN_NAME" <<< "$KUBE_GET"
```

This will find the string ": " in the line found by grep and then return the rest of the line after that string:

```
sed 's/.*: \(.*\)$/\1/'
```

Comment: This gives not just the exact value, some other outputs as well. Like below. `100`
`consul-write`
`/api/v1/namespaces/banuka-test/secrets/consul-write`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). Please check its [document](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) for installation details.
After you installed yq, you could put the following command in your command line:

```
# yq r your_yaml_file 'data."consul-write"'
```

If it worked, put it in a bash file.